# Динамический анонимный тип

Tags: c#

обычно перед создание анонимного типа сразу известно какие поля будут в него входить, но что, если у меня нет этой информации и мне требуется создать объект количество полей (и их имена) которое неизвестно, оно станет известно лишь во время выполнения программы.

Comment: Для этого есть [`dynamic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот тип "анонимный" для Вас, для компилятора он вполне определенный - именно за счет известной структуры объекта и соответствующего типа, созданного компилятором.

Используйте словарь.